# PreviewProvider doesn't work in Widget Extension

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I have this view

```
import SwiftUI

struct CurrentOrderView: View {
  let order: CurrentOrder

  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
      HStack {
        Text("Order:")
        Text(order.orderId)
      }

      HStack {
        Image(uiImage: deliveryImage)
          .resizable()
          .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
          .frame(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
        Text(order.formattedDeliveryTimeString)
      }
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    .padding()
    .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.orange, .yellow]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
  }
}

// MARK: - Private

private extension CurrentOrderView {
  private var deliveryImage: UIImage {
    switch order.status {
    case .driverOnTheWayToRestaurant:
      return UIImage(named: "pin-restaurant") ?? UIImage()
    case .driverOnTheWayToUser:
      return UIImage(named: "rider") ?? UIImage()
    }
  }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    Group {
      CurrentOrderView(
        order: CurrentOrderEntryPlaceholderBuilder()
          .entry(with: .snapshot).order
      )
      .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 200, height: 100))
    }
  }
}
#endif
```

In canvas I see:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `previewLayout`, use `WidgetPreviewContext`

The following would add a preview for a medium widget. `.systemMedium` can also be `.systemSmall` and `.systemLarge`

```swift
#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    Group {
      CurrentOrderView(
        order: CurrentOrderEntryPlaceholderBuilder()
          .entry(with: .snapshot).order
      )
      .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemMedium))
    }
  }
}
#endif
```

Comment: but I don't want this view to be full widget size, actually it takes only 50% of widget, what should I do?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @PaulT.

Comment: I mean in my case CurrentOrderView should take 50% of widget width (because widget constists of CurrentOrderView + AnotherView). But using your code it shows CurrentOrderView with 100% width

Comment: @PaulT. I only see one view in your question

Comment: I understand, but that's why I set size manually in the question 

Comment: ok, anyway  +1, but if you have any ideas how to set a custom size in canvas, please let me know

Comment: @PaulT. Thanks, and I’ll let you know

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you don't want to preview a widget but just a view.

What you can do is to move `CurrentOrderView` and its `Entry` to another file.

Then add this file to the main App target (apart from the Widget target).

Also make sure to rename previews struct, so the name is different than the auto-generated `ContentView_Previews` previews.

This way your previews will work as expected:

```
struct CurrentOrderView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    Group {
      CurrentOrderView(
        order: CurrentOrderEntryPlaceholderBuilder()
          .entry(with: .snapshot).order
      )
      .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 200, height: 100))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it was promising, but it doesn't work https://take.ms/bFBQv

Comment: Can you also try to change the name of `ContentView_Previews`?

Answer (score 1):

Add `previewContext` to your `PreviewProvider`

```
#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    Group {
      CurrentOrderView(
        order: CurrentOrderEntryPlaceholderBuilder()
          .entry(with: .snapshot).order
      )
      .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemMedium))
    }
  }
}
#endif
```

Comment: but I don't want this view to be full widget size, actually it takes only 50% of widget, what should I do?